# Differences between DataStage 11.3 vs 11.7

Tags: datastage

I want to migrate DataStage projects 11.3 to 11.7, I was wondering what problems there may be at the time of migration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using all the latest Stages/Connector in V11.3, you shouldn't hit any issues and it should be a simple export/import.

However, if you use some deprecated stages then you need to run the Connector Migration Tool to replace them - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.migtool.doc/topics/connectormigrationtool_intro.html

You also need to check whether all the Source and Target you are using are still supported, e.g. Oracle Connector for V11.3 support Oracle 10gR2, 11gR1 and 11gR2 while V11.7 only support minimum of 11gR2.